# Missed online exam, Is there anything I can do?

Tags: advisor, grading, online-exam

Prior to this morning, there was no indication that the exam would only be at a specific time window. Nothing on the syllabus, class schedule, calendar, announcements.... I could go on. Nada- nothing until this morning. We only knew in advance that it was today and what it covered. There is no meetup or log on time for this class. Because of this, I assumed that it would be due before 11:59 PM just like all our other assignments and didn't set an alarm. Woke up and realized I missed it. This is our first exam and it's worth 20%. Emailed the professor explaining that I'm a transient student and that I missed it due to the reasons above. At my home institution, all my online professors told us at least the day beforehand about the start and end time of their exams.

As expected, our professor replied, saying that I need a valid excuse (understandable). I take Sertraline and it commonly affects my sleep. I haven't really been taking it like I should be and I think I might be going through withdrawal. But, that's a whole different story and I'm not sure if that would be classified as a severe illness to even be considered a valid excuse. So, I don't know if I should even try to fight this and try to get proper documentation. The earliest that I'm able to go to my doctor is on the 6th.

I'm sorry, that I'm a bit all over the place. I'm just overwhelmed by the idea of fighting this, or if I even can.

Comment: How’d this turn out and what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

Little you can do beyond appeal to the professor.

But perhaps your institution has an ombuds who will intervene on your behalf, or an office that deals with exceptions for people with medical (and/or) other conditions.

Since it is the first exam, if you show a completely different profile in subsequent exams and other work, perhaps the professor would be willing to give you a higher overall grade than your average indicates. That happened to me once. Every grade was better than the one before and I wound up with an A for the course despite failing the first exam.

No guarantees. You may just have to live with it.